# How to detect/find 64 bit struct alignment issues

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

We have a code base that is rather old that we are migrating to 64-bit to make use of some new 3rd party 64-bit tools.  We are running on Windows 7, using VS2010, and code written in C++.

We spent the last two days trying to figure out an issue where a member variable was not getting set to the expected value.  Using the VS2010 memory debugger, we were able to see that member variable memory locations were offset by four bytes.  Some research lead us to struct alignment and 64 bit.

It turns out the first variable defined in the class was a 32-bit integer, the second variable was a pointer.  If we moved the pointer to the top of the class, all member variables aligned up correctly.  This fixed the issue.

We also noticed that either

1. adding a four byte buffer to the top of class "fixed" the issue
2. setting pack alignment to four bytes also "fixed" the issue.

The question is, how do you detect these errors?  We set the warning level to EnabelAllWarnings and tried several static c++ analyzers, but no luck.

One example where this happens.  I can't show the other due to an NDA.

```cpp
class CTaskBar
{
public:

    bool CreateTaskbarIcon( HWND hWnd,
                        HINSTANCE hInstance,
                        UINT unNotifyMessage,
                        UINT unIcon,
                        LPCTSTR szCaption)
    {
        if (hWnd == NULL)
            return false;
        if (hInstance == NULL)
            return false;

        m_hWnd = hWnd;
        m_hInstance = hInstance;

        m_NIDTaskbarIconData.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
        m_NIDTaskbarIconData.hWnd   = m_hWnd;
        m_NIDTaskbarIconData.uID    = IDI_TASKBARICON;

        if ( unIcon ) {

        if ( m_hTaskbarIcon )
            DestroyIcon( m_hTaskbarIcon );

        m_hTaskbarIcon = ::LoadIcon( m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE( unIcon ) );

        m_NIDTaskbarIconData.hIcon  = m_hTaskbarIcon;
        m_NIDTaskbarIconData.uFlags |= NIF_ICON;
    }

    if ( unNotifyMessage ) {
        m_NIDTaskbarIconData.uCallbackMessage = unNotifyMessage;
        m_NIDTaskbarIconData.uFlags |= NIF_MESSAGE;
    }

    if ( szCaption ) {
        strcpy(m_NIDTaskbarIconData.szTip, szCaption);
        m_NIDTaskbarIconData.uFlags |= NIF_TIP;
    }

    // The Shell_NotifyIcon call will add the icon to the task bar.
    if ( Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &m_NIDTaskbarIconData) )
        return true;

    return false;
}

private:
    NOTIFYICONDATA  m_NIDTaskbarIconData;
    HINSTANCE       m_hInstance;
    HWND            m_hWnd;
    HMENU           m_hTaskbarMenu;
    HICON           m_hTaskbarIcon;
};
```

Basically, the application crashes at Shell_NotifyIcon deep inside the Windows API calls.  If we look in the memory debugger, we can see memory getting set, but offset by four bytes.  If I move m_NIDTaskbarIconData to just after m_hTaskbarIcon.  Everything looks correct in the memory debugger and no crash.

Comment: When you compile for 64-bit, all structs with pointers should be aligned to at least 8 bytes anyway. Is there some pragma packing going on? (EDIT: Oh, I just saw your second bullet. There *is* packing going on.)

Comment: This smells like undefined behavior to me (maybe even a one definition rule violation), and if that's the case, it's often very hard for static checkers to detect. Can you provide any more specific details about the problem?

Comment: @Mysticial There is packing going on in the sense that we know we can set it and things seem to fix themselves.  Both applications do some packing because they send and receive binary packed messages via TCP.  When we realized that setting packing made things go away, we did look back at the single header file that uses packing to ensure that packing was reset at the bottom, rechecking with #pragma pack(show) to verify.

Comment: I don't see a good signal.  Not completely initializing NOTIFYICONDATA and not using NIM_SETVERSION, perhaps.  If it actually *crashes* inside the shell then you have a pretty good hint that it is accessing released memory or you are now witnessing the side-effects of a latent heap corruption problem that already existed in the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we did do a lot of searching on 64-bit C/C++ applications.  As Andrey Cpp pointed out and linked to, there is a struct alignment issue based on the order and size of member variables.  Unfortunately PVS-Studio did not point to this issue.  I don't believe it to be an error on PVS-Studio.  Further research, and trial and error, led us to trying to build the project in VS2013.  The issue is gone in VS2013.  The closest thing I can find to explain why it works in VS2013 is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx).

> On x64, the object layout of a class may change from previous releases. If it has a virtual function but it doesn’t have a base class that has a virtual function, the object model of the compiler inserts a pointer to a virtual function table after the data member layout. This means the layout may not be optimal in all cases. In previous releases, an optimization for x64 would try to improve the layout for you, but because it failed to work correctly in complex code situations, **it was removed in Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2013**.

It looks to be a bug in VS2010 that is fixed in VS2013.  The memory debugger in VS2013 shows the alignment as I would expect.